# How to compute dot product of vector of dual numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra

How can we compute the dot product of vectors of dual numbers? Is it same as `dot product` of complex numbers?

Comment: It's worth noting that, for complex numbers, while there is a bilinear "dot product" $w_1z_1+\cdots+w_nz_n$ it is more natural to use the sesquilinear "inner product" $\overline{w_1}z_1+\cdots+\overline{w_n}z_n$ instead. Similar dichotomy for dual numbers. Note the conjugate of a dual number is $\overline{a+b\varepsilon}=a-b\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You just multiply the corresponding elements of both vectors, and then take into consideration $\displaystyle \epsilon^2=0$, just as you would with $i^2=-1$.

Comment: good catch! @RussellB appreciate that