# how to compute norm of a vector of dual numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

My Question is,

How to compute norm of a vector of dual numbers? Is is same as `complex number` because the `dot` product is the same with the difference of $\epsilon^2 = 0$ as opposed to $i^2 = -1$.

Comment: This is essentially a word for word duplicate of [MSE question 3251460](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3251460) "How  to compute dot product of vector of dual numbers?" with "norm" instead of "dot product".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define the norm of a dual number $z=a+b\varepsilon$ by $|z|^2 = z\overline{z}$ where $\overline{z} = a-b\varepsilon$ you get
$$
|z|^2 = (a+b\varepsilon)(a-b\varepsilon) = a^2-b^2\varepsilon^2 = a^2
$$
so that $|z|=|a|$. Note however, that this is not a "norm" is the sense that $|z|=0$ does not imply $z=0$.

Now you can do the same for vectors of dual numbers by letting $\langle u, v\rangle = u^T \overline{w}$ but you won't get a positive definite product and hence not a norm.

Comment: Thanks @Christoph. Does that mean Dual number vectors does not have a proper `norm`. Does that have something to their inability to form fields?

Comment: You could also define the norm of $z=a+b\varepsilon$ as $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, i.e., just take the standard norm of $\Bbb R^2$. If you do that, you satisfy all the usual norm-axioms but loose multplicativity, since then $1=|\varepsilon|^2 \neq |\varepsilon^2| = 0$.